# Javascript/ AngularJS to Ask Consumers to Download iOS/ Android Apps

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs

can't seem to find this anywhere on google. Any ideas where I can find some code that asks a user to download our iOS/ Android apps when they come to our site on a mobile device? Preferably wrapped in AngularJS and preferably with cookie support so that people don't have to say no every time.

I'd imagine something like this:

```
if(userIsIOS && didNotAlreadySayNo) {Ask to download iOS app}
```

Answer (score 1):

For iOS devices that browse using Safari (which should be the vast majority), Apple actually provides developers with a consistent tool: **Smart Banners**

It simply consists in a `<meta>` tag added in the `<head>` of your document, like this:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

You can find the full documentation on Apple website: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html